# Dataframe to List Issue

Tags: python, dataframe

So I am new to dataframes in python and trying to wrap my head around it. I saw this function and it was saying convert to a list but I am not entirely sure how to approach it:

```
def correlation (fname1, attr1, fname2, attr2):


correlation_coefficient=np.corrcoef(attr1,attr2)
return correlation_coefficient
fname1=pd.read_csv('./data/test1.csv')
attr1=fname1['Open']
fname2=pd.read_csv('./data/test2.csv')
attr2=fname2['Open']
correlation (fname1, attr1, fname2, attr2)
```

So I did my research and was following along with this source:
[Convert Python Pandas DataFrame To List](https://appdividend.com/2020/04/25/how-to-convert-python-pandas-dataframe-to-list/)

I kind of got what it was saying but went on to read here:

[Python Pandas Read CSV – Load Data from CSV Files](https://www.shanelynn.ie/python-pandas-read-csv-load-data-from-csv-files/)

Then I went on to this:

[How to Convert Pandas DataFrame into a List](https://datatofish.com/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-list/)

I think I got the gist of it so I started playing with the function and did this:

```
def correlation (fname1, attr1, fname2, attr2):


correlation_coefficient=np.corrcoef(attr1,attr2)
return correlation_coefficient
fname1=pd.read_csv('./data/test1.csv')
fname1.values.tolist()
attr1=fname1['Open']
fname2=pd.read_csv('./data/test2.csv')
fname2.values.tolist()
attr2=fname2['Open']
correlation (fname1, attr1, fname2, attr2)
```

But I don't think I am on the right track. Can some insight be shed for me to understand more where I am actually going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The Function is not indented properly, try making the indentation

```
def correlation (fname1, attr1, fname2, attr2):
  correlation_coefficient=np.corrcoef(attr1,attr2)
  return correlation_coefficient
        
fname1=pd.read_csv('./data/test1.csv')
fname1.values.tolist()
attr1=fname1['Open']
fname2=pd.read_csv('./data/test2.csv')
fname2.values.tolist()
attr2=fname2['Open']
correlation (fname1, attr1, fname2, attr2)
```

And your code does the operation such that it first reads the data in the test1.csv file and then we get the values from the column "open" in the file test1.csv and then it reads the data from the test2.csv and then we get the values from the column "open". then we pass that data to the function the function will do the operation of getting the co-relationship between the attr1 and attr2 which is finding relationship between the "open" column in test1.csv and test2.csv